# Character encoding issue with Tomcat

Tags: jsp, tomcat, character-encoding

There is strange character encoding going on. I am using JSP (JSTL) and Struts with Tomat 6.

I have my JSP page encoding as such:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

The issue is when I try to pass the url using encodeURI as such:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          $('#mailer_filter').change(function(){
            var val = $(this).val();
            console.log(val);
            console.log(escape(val));
            console.log(encodeURI(val));
            location.href = 'mailList.a?' + encodeURI($(this).val());
          });
        </script>
```

the parameter on the action (java end) comes out as:

```
Gaz MÃ©tro
```

however on the front end it is displayed as:

```
Gaz Métro
```

which is the correct way. What I can do about this??

Comment: Where do you see the value on the Java end?  In the log file?  If so, it may be that the editor that you're using to read the log file isn't expecting UTF-8...

Answer (score 20):

Do following

1) HTML Code

```
 <meta contentType="text/html; charset="UTF-8"/>
```

2) Browser Setting for IE
 View -- Encoding -- Unicode (UTF-8)

3) Tomcat Server
 server.xml - In Connector tag added "URIEncoding" attribute as

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

catalina.sh/catalina.bat - added following

```
set JAVA_OPTS=--Xms256m -Xmx1024m -Xss268k -server -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djavax.servlet.request.encoding=UTF-8 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

set CATALINA_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding="UTF-8"
```

4) MIME type of response should be "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Comment: I've been searching for a day to get this sorted out.  All worked fine on Jetty, but when deploying to tomcat my umlauts were going missing.  Thank you!

Comment: 1) 2) and 4) have totally no effect on the problem as described in the question. That leaves only 3) as the correct answer. More specifically, to fix request query string encoding (for GET). In order to fix request body encoding (for POST) as well as response body encoding, you need other fixes as well, you can find all of them in abovelinked duplicate.

Answer (score 12):

Have you followed these steps?

http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q8

**Copied below:**

Using UTF-8 as your character encoding for everything is a safe bet. This should work for pretty much every situation.

In order to completely switch to using UTF-8, you need to make the following changes:

1. Set URIEncoding="UTF-8" on your  in server.xml. References: HTTP Connector, AJP Connector.
2. Use a character encoding filter with the default encoding set to UTF-8
3. Change all your JSPs to include charset name in their contentType.

   For example, use `<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>` for the usual JSP pages and `<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` for the pages in XML syntax (aka JSP Documents).
4. Change all your servlets to set the content type for responses and to include charset name in the content type to be UTF-8.

   Use `response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8")` or `response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")`.
5. Change any content-generation libraries you use (Velocity, Freemarker, etc.) to use UTF-8 and to specify UTF-8 in the content type of the responses that they generate.
6. Disable any valves or filters that may read request parameters before your character encoding filter or jsp page has a chance to set the encoding to UTF-8. For more information see http://www.mail-archive.com/users@tomcat.apache.org/msg21117.html.

Comment: thanks so much Paul... I've tried all of the above.. still no luck, i've been trying to find a solution, i've even seen solutions suggested to encode to UTF-8 manually! I do not want to use this option though... basically this post is similar to my problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213377/handle-french-characters-in-java

however those suggestions don't work either.

Comment: I've seen **6** responsible for this 'in the wild', using WebSphere Portal Server. Try and trace each request, and if *anything* tries to read a request parameter before the correct encoding is set, then the value will be read as ISO8859-1 (if I remember correctly, this is specified in the servlet spec.).

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the URIEncoding parameter of your tomcat connector (in the server.xml) to UTF-8:

E.g.:

```
<Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
           maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
           enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
           connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion... I attempted this before posting, did not resolve the issue.

Comment: This has nothing to do with output encoding. It will only affect values read from a client, and only for GET parameter values.