# How to use utf-8 in Servlet handler for request parameters?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, character-encoding

I have a default installation of Tomcat 8.5.6. It seems like UTF-8 encoded requests are not being interpreted correctly, even though the docs say the default (if not in strict mode) should be UTF-8 everywhere these days. My java POST requests look like:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));
...
```

Testing, I see the tilde character ñ is not decoded correctly in my servlet handler:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, ...) {
        String tildeTest = request.getParam("foo"); // no good.
    }
}
```

if I explicitly set the encoding on the request before access, it decodes properly:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, ...) {
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    String tildeTest = request.getParam("foo"); // works!
    ...
}
```

so I'm not sure if:

1. Tomcat 8.5.6 is not really using UTF-8 everywhere, and I need to set that manually in the config files somewhere.
2. My http request is missing some header which tells Tomcat which encoding to use - perhaps the http post is defaulting to some other encoding which Tomcat is just honoring.

Anyone know which one?

Thanks

Comment: Point 3) of answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11185963/3511123 could be what you need. (I mean the `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` attribute for `<Connector ... />` config.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek yeah I saw that, but the docs say that everything should be utf-8 by default now - wanted to get clarification about why this appears to not be utf-8 before I start changing stuff.

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding

> POST requests should specify the encoding of the parameters and values
>   they send. Since many clients fail to set an explicit encoding, the
>   default is used (ISO-8859-1).

**[What can you recommend to just make everything work? (How to use UTF-8 everywhere).](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q8)**

There are 6 ways listed to ensure this, for servlet requests 1,2 should be relevant

1. Set URIEncoding="UTF-8" on your  in server.xml. References: HTTP Connector, AJP Connector.
2. Use a character encoding filter with the default encoding set to UTF-8