# UTF-8 (Arabic) query String parameter is distorted when viewing in JSP

Tags: jsp, utf-8, jstl, servlet-filters, arabic-support

I have 2 jsp pages (a.jsp, b.jsp) both of them are showing the UTF-8 Strings correctly (i mean the arabic characters) also i can insert and retrieve to/from database without any issue.As i am using a character encoding filter for all request calls.

The problem is when i am adding a hyperlink with a Arabic query string parameter like this

a.jsp :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

</head>
<body>
     <a  href='/LoadProductByTypeId?abc=عربي'>link</a>

</body>

 </html>
```

b.jsp :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

</head>
<body>
    <c:out value="${param.abc}" />

</body>

 </html>
```

in b.jsp the result comes as :

Ø¹Ø±Ø¨Ù

when i tried to print out the value of the parameter in the encoding filter it came as the same 'distorted' value.

Any help , really appreciated.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11185963/3511123 - it might be what you need. (I mean the `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` attribute for `<Connector ... />` config.)

Comment: @JozefChocholacek "URIEncoding" solve it ..add your answer to be accepted :)