# ? instead of polish characters in tomcat 8.5

Tags: tomcat

I have troubles with tomcat encoding. I get instead of polish char like ąęłć.

[Character encoding issue with Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089783/character-encoding-issue-with-tomcat)

I was trying to use it, but doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

If previous tips in given link still doesn't work you can check the database column. I have in **SQL Server** the `VARCHAR` which is **non-Unicode** type (1 byte per character). After change to `NVARCHAR` which **is Unicode** (2 bytes per character) I have finally polish characters in database.