# dataForm breaks Turkish characters

Tags: javascript, ajax, postgresql, character-encoding, turkish

I found an issue trying to update a **Postgres database (UTF-8)** from an ajax call which contains Turkish characters in their body.
 I have a simple json with id and name attributes, name contains 'Kumar oyunları risk taşır'
 and on the database is saved "Kumar oyunlar�� risk ta����r"

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#sendToServer").click(function(){
            var json = '{"name":"Kumar oyunları risk taşır", "id": 123'}; 
            var server = "http://10.16.0.89:8080";
            var apiURL = server + "/api/content/publish/create";
            var dataform = new FormData();
            dataform.append('json', JSON.stringify(json));

            getURL = $.ajax({
                url: apiURL,
                type: 'PUT',
                cache: false,
                data: dataform,
                contentType:false,               
                success: function (result, request, response, data, status, xhr) {
                    alert('Success!');
                }
            });
        });
...
<button id="sendToServer">Send to server</button>
```

There is no issue if json is used instead of dataform **( data: json )** BUT I really need it to use it because I gotta append a file in my app.

Comment: Without the server side code we can only guess

Comment: One detail I forgot to say that it was working fine in my local environment, ok, finally as I thought the problem was Tomcat encoding, I've just followed solution on  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089783/character-encoding-issue-with-tomcat and that's it

Answer (score 0):

Problem was on Tomcat side, I just follow this solution:  [Character encoding issue with Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089783/character-encoding-issue-with-tomcat) and it's working perfect now.